# anti-theft system

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to create an anti-theft system, I use a Pir sensor for motion detection and a esp8266 to send a variable (1 or 0) to a local server with tcp protocol and at command . when I turn on the arduino it sends a 0 (no movement) but after it sends only 1 (there is a movement), 
she doesn't return to the initial state. 
 I tested the sensor alone, it works very well . 
Any help please ?

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Serial1(1,0); //RX, TX
#define DEBUG true
void setup() {
   Serial1.begin(115200);
   pinMode(A0, INPUT);
   pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(void) {
   if(digitalRead(A0) == HIGH)
   {
      tone(8, 50);
      Serial.println("hight");
      send(1); 
   }
   else
   {        
      noTone(8);
      Serial.println("low"); 
      send(0);
   }
}

void send(int val)
{

   String rest1 = "AT+CIPMUX=1";
   rest1 += "\r\n";
   sendData(rest1, 2000, 0);

   char inv = '"';
   String add = "AT+CIPSTART";
   add += "=1,";
   add += inv;
   add += "TCP";
   add += inv;
   add += ",";
   add += inv;
   add += "192.168.46.102";  // Host_server_name
   add += inv;
   add += ",";
   add += "80";
   add += "\r\n";
   sendData(add, 3000, 0);  // Establishing a TCP Connection. ( AT+CIPSTART = "TCP","Host_server_name",80 )

   String rest = "AT+CIPSEND=1,87";
   rest += "\r\n";
   sendData(rest, 2000, 0); //Number of characters to send. ( "AT+CIPSEND=90" )

   String hostt = "GET /sp_notification/upload.php?value=";
   hostt += val;
   hostt +=" HTTP/1.1";
   hostt += "\r\n";
   hostt += "HOST:192.168.46.102";
   hostt += "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
   String views = sendData(hostt, 2000, 0);  // GET request ( GET /apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
                                             //               Host: Host_server_name ) 
}

String sendData(String command, const int Goldout, boolean debug)
{
   String response = "";

   Serial1.print(command); // send the read character to the Serial1

   long int Gold = millis();

   while ( (Gold + Goldout) > millis())
   {
      while (Serial1.available())
      {

         // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
         char c = Serial1.read(); // read the next character.
         response += c;
      }
   }

   if (debug)
   {
      Serial.print(response);
   }
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Did you try other pins? Why using an analog pin? And I assume you see never the text 'low' except during startup?

Comment: yes , i don"t see the text   , i just started using arduino i don"t know difference between pins

Comment: Does the tone stop? PS you can use `\"` to add a `"` inside a string. So for example `add = "AT+CIPSTART=1,\"TCP\", ...";`

Comment: A0 to A7 are analog (only) pins, the others are digital, you can try to use another pin (except 0 and 1 which are used for RX/TX UART communication), but 2 or 3 should be ok, reconnect your sensor to pin 2 or 3 too, and check if that changes.

Comment: yes , bro it s worked , but sometimes even if buzzer run he don't send (1) any suggestion ?

Comment: Gerben , when i used analogic port the tone didn"t stop

Comment: Michel Keijzers , the sensor find a great difficulty to detect my movement